# How to share labels in faceted nested charts of "Vega Lite"?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I want to use "Vega Lite" to achieve the faceted nesting effect similar to tableau. Although "Vega Lite" can also be achieved, the display effect is not satisfactory, which is mainly reflected in that each sub chart has its own coordinate axis label, and the information density is not high. Tableau is much more compact.

This is an example of tableau:
[image]

This is an example of vega-lite:
[image]

```
{
  "data": {"url": "https://uniplore-source.oss-cn-chengdu.aliyuncs.com/other/orders2.csv"},
  "spacing": 0,
  "facet": {"row": {"field": "快递方式","type": "nominal",
   "header":{"labelExpr": "null"}
  }},

  "spec": {
    "facet": {"column": {"field": "类别","type": "nominal","header":{"labelExpr": "null"}}},
    "spacing": 0,
    "spec": {
      "spacing": 0,
      "facet": {
        "column": {
          "field": "子类别","type": "nominal"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "facet": {
          "column": {
            "field": "细分","type": "nominal"
          }
        },
        "spec": {
          "mark": "bar",
          "spacing": 0,
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "细分","type": "nominal"
            },
            "y": {"aggregate": "sum","field":"销售额"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can view my example [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA28QAspQA4Gc4B6IxAOwEtdUB7ZAUwFp8aUBjegOhv30bbL9M9MgHMwiThFQUAnuTb5ObGgFsiNKMOQbkYesnwAmZfgBuIAL4AaEPlwQ2FMfAAMtgGaP6UeKGQ0AO5+IB4U9KhgGIDX+oBICYCdpoDw+iC2ULK49Bhkas7SKVj0EPrIIagQAEYRAKIAHrglcCBkiKjolu229vRsIV4cvgggKqiIqmS94ZEYgN4+gNRK+WkZWTlkebbCRQalFdV1DU0tbR12Dk4ucO4n3SH2js6ibp7eA6DDo+ODYRFRjYAK2nMLdKZRrZVS5I6dDI9T7PEJvMYTb4YQBjfoAwJUBSxBKzyxy60NAqggyAA1hhykT8rczg8LrYRCowPcQjVEVNGmiMcCmti2rZZCEIKJRAxRNAufhRvkvmyQIAAVMAdKqAXIyrO1VZYgA).

In fact, the same amount of information can not be displayed on one screen with Vega Lite.

I have tried some configurations, but the effect is not obvious.

I want to know if there is any way Vega Lite can achieve the display effect of tableau.
The most important of these is shared labels.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean shared axes, then you can do this using facet.

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/facet.html

[image]

**Edit 1**

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQspAjhoQmAE5xBwiAH0mSLYLgBPRSAAmcaFpo5M7eegAq8AARudemhE9rfxxBJHNPJnCAITgoAGs4LU84TE8kQUpPeEEcOGtkiEwkJn0YTwhkPU8EBkFnELs0gKRPQBwCHDYAd0SAM1rq2JgkWX8ETx62JIZZWy1C4aDZMk8aWUxEpChnOQDV8swGIMa2HqyutM8dCA7ZCDhAuFyZgLlkgA8Q4aRMSfDiExoxTMEEAuASZAASiXu3Uujy0bGsDCg9xa2l0+k8J08URMZnC5houmsAR68LG9HuAEYAJwAZgADBAFJ4oGwEA11p5OnQyshVvw4D0erFMC8tLNVssfuNNjRhEVOaz2QCZLJKFZrN8UKhQAxTBpNUUCMZTBYpKqQABfJTILRxDQdVaYKzwGhkLBoUCFR5oSkAJmtIDgslZizInpAPU2KQj11lSwj8M6aH4ABZ6YGeoTBNYNBARFZMOZchpJot0lZWYIGAhbmg-UoZFpnTqQGwcBo1EFhlYs0SNAT+4H4EhZhHQkxdABRD5aDSyWqCK2Bt4RpBkMg6CjrTt5QHyJR9nMD7O5pRFkvoACODGGzgVNFIVmg6XUrYAXok2Ggo4I7pbA0sVsj1zdB-gcFJLHPYs3zbcVVgrRtJhbEB+FXQMq0mCMQIHOATELGD5zZBClwAy0gA)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "name": "trellis_barley",
  "description": "The Trellis display by Becker et al. helped establish small multiples as a “powerful mechanism for understanding interactions in studies of how a response depends on explanatory variables”. Here we reproduce a trellis of Barley yields from the 1930s, complete with main-effects ordering to facilitate comparison.",
  "data": {"url": "data/barley.json"},
  "mark": "point",
  "height": {"step": 12},
  "encoding": {
    "facet": {
      "spacing": {"row": -40},
      "field": "site",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "columns": 2,
      "sort": {"op": "median", "field": "yield"},
      "header":{"labelExpr": "null"}
    },
    "x": {
      "aggregate": "median",
      "field": "yield",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false}
    },
    "y": {"field": "variety", "type": "ordinal", "sort": "-x"},
    "color": {"field": "year", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I didn't describe my problem clearly. I have used facet, but the display effect is poor. For example, in your example, if I want to make each sub chart more compact, I need to remove the labels at the top of the sub chart in line 2 and line 3. But Vega Lite doesn't seem to have such an option. I tried to set the title font size to 0, but the title in line 1 is also hidden.

Comment: You can do this via a header. I have updated the answer for you.

Comment: I know how my actual example differs from yours. I use multiple nested facts.I have updated my questions, and you can take a look at the examples I have given.Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand the language so it is hard to say but you have 3 facets going on which is unusual. Is this just a grid of grouped column charts? https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/bar_grouped.html

I think you need to create a grid facet of just column charts.

Comment: In fact, I am building an infinite faceted nested system based on "Vega Lite". As you can see, I am still a novice.

Comment: Using Vega Lite should not achieve my goal. I should take a look at Vega.